# rsync in not working on startup?

Tags: linux

Hi I'm new in Linux and I have been trying synchronize two folder with rsync command. I'm using CentOS and when I execute command (`#rsync -zvr /tmp/f1/ /tmp/f2/`) through command line is working fine, but through rc.local on rebooting is not working. The following message is showed:

```
sending incremental file list

rsync: change_dir "/tmp/f1" failed: Permission denied (13)

rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/tmp/f2/": Permission denied (13)

rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(554) [receiver=3.0.6]

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]

rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Please some help?

Comment: What is the output of ``getenforce`` as root?

Comment: SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having trouble with [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux). SELinux is a module which allows for much more fine grained access control than file system permissions and ACLs do. Among others, it will disallow access to files for rsync by default, if it is not run by a user from a terminal. Now how can you let it access the files you want?

There are two options. If you are only dealing with directories *no other service* (including httpd or such) needs access to, you can do the following:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_t "/tmp/f1(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_t "/tmp/f2(/.*)?"
```

This should persistently change the SELinux rules to make the directories /tmp/f1 and /tmp/f2 accessible by rsync. In fact, it will set the `public_content_t` type on the directories and the files. Nodes with that type are accessible by rsync. However, there is a catch, as mentioned: A node (directory or file) can only have *one* type. Many services have other requirements for files they access, (e.g. sshd requires `ssh_t`), so you cannot do this in /etc for example.

Another solution is to persistently allow rsync access to *all* files. This is fine if you do not run the rsync daemon:

```
setsebool -P rsync_full_access 1
```

Afterwards, rsync will be able to access all files, even if run from init and not from a users terminal.

---

**Why does it make a difference if rsync is started by a daemon or by a user?**

(this is only true for the most common, `targeted` policy)

SELinux knows users, and normal users use the SELinux-user unconfined_u. unconfined_u is allowed to do pretty much everything the file system ACLs allow it to do. However, init and such are running as system_u, and system_u is far more constrained. This helps to prevent attacks on httpd and other exposed daemons.

Comment: With second command I got this:

libsemanage.dbase_llist_set: record not found in the database
libsemanage.dbase_llist_set: could not set record value
Could not change boolean rsync_full_access
Could not change policy booleans

Comment: I have tried on the first way and this is what I got on the screen, after I called rc.local through command line:

sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/tmp/f1" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/tmp/f2/": Permission denied (13)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(554) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]

Comment: Can you do an ``mkdir /tmp/f1`` and an ``ls -dZ /tmp/f1``. What is the SELinux context of the directory? (the string which is like ``foo_u:bar_r:baz_t``)

Comment: the first command gave me:
mkdir: cannot create directory `/tmp/f1': File exists
and the second: 
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 /tmp/f1

Comment: How does the ``ls -dZ`` look after ``restorecon -R /tmp/f1``?

Comment: dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0      .

Comment: do you have some idea ? :/ something else that I should try ?

Comment: [Dan Walsh has more on this](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/61646.html). Can you try ``semanage fcontext -m -t bin_t /usr/bin/rsync``? This is potentially dangerous if you use rsync as a daemon.

Comment: I got this message: 
/usr/sbin/semanage: File context for /usr/bin/rsync is not defined

Comment: Mainly my idea was to make server that I will use for Sub Versioning (SVN) of development of the projects and to backup the content of the repositories on the another location. I try to use the folowing command in rc.local #su - root -c 'nohup watch -n 1 rsync -zvr /opt/svn/repositories/ /var/sync_folder/ > /dev/null 2>&1 &' . When I have tried to locate the problem and I have found that I have problem with rsync command. If there is some way to do the same that the command does, please give me some directions?

Comment: If you really want to run this every second (that’s what I read from the watch-line), rsync is probably required. Apart from that, can you try the command from above with ``-a`` instead of ``-m``? Also, please tell me the context of /usr/bin/rsync (using ``ls -Z``) and run a restorecon on /usr/bin/rsync. Note that you have to replace /usr/bin/rsync with /bin/rsync if rsync is installed there!

Answer (score 0):

If you have just rebooted /tmp will have been cleared and so /tmp/f1 and /tmp/f2 will not exist

rc.local usually runs quite late in the boot sequence so I'd guess that /tmp is mounted rw but it's possible that it is still only mounted ro

Comment: If `/tmp` was mounted R/O, the error message would be `read-only filesystem` instead of `permission denied`, though (and `stat()` would succeed in the first place).

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi yep, I agree.  But there has to be some reason that /tmp/f2 cannot be made

Comment: But the problem is with any folder on any other location. The command is working through command line but not through execution rc.local. I try to change permission of the command in rc.local with adding su - root -c "..command.." but still the same problem.

Comment: Mainly my idea was to make server that I will use for Sub Versioning (SVN) of development of the projects and to backup the content of the repositories on the another location. I try to use the folowing command in rc.local #su - root -c 'nohup watch -n 1 rsync -zvr /opt/svn/repositories/ /var/sync_folder/ > /dev/null 2>&1 &' . When I have tried to locate the problem and I have found that I have problem with rsync command. If there is some way to do the same that the command does, please give me some directions.